# Angular chart.js chart scale

Tags: angular, chart.js, scale

I'm using chart.js in angular to achieve some results in a chart. What am I looking for is to have a certain number of number that dinamically change every 50ms. I've done this and here's the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GEu6seOu1fbh9dnuSjMV?p=preview

Package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.7.19",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

Component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Chart, ChartPoint } from 'chart.js';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public isAlive = true;
    public chart: Chart;
    public data = [];

    canvas: any;
    ctx: any;

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        Observable.interval(50)
            .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
            .subscribe(
                succ => {
                    if (!this.chart) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (this.data.length > 200) {
                        this.data.splice(0, 1);
                        this.chart.data.labels.splice(0, 1);
                    }

                    this.data.push(new Date().getSeconds());
                    this.chart.data.labels.push(new Date().getSeconds().toString() + '-');
                    this.chart.update();
                }
            );
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (!this.chart) {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: this.data,
                        fill: false,
                        showLine: true,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 2
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: false,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js - Fixed X and Y Axis',
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    elements: {
                        point: {
                            radius: 0
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {

                        xAxes: [{
                            display: false,
                            ticks: {

                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                min: 0,
                                max: 60
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

            for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                this.data.push(new Date().getSeconds());
                this.chart.data.labels.push(new Date().getSeconds().toString() + '-');
            }
            this.chart.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Component.html :

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

Module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem is that I've to pre-render (in this case) 200 elements because, in this way, the chart will set the right scale. If I don't put before this code :

```
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                    this.data.push(new Date().getSeconds());
                    this.chart.data.labels.push(new Date().getSeconds().toString() + '-');
                }
                this.chart.update();
```

You will see the chart adjusting the scale unitil the if-statement that check if the array contains more than 200 elements is fired. What am I try to achieve is to have the right scale without first looping 200 times to put in the data "fake" elements.

Does anyone know the right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

edit: In light of question edits this answer is not relevant.

I'm not sure If I fully understand your question, but I was having a problem with the scaling animation in angular-charts and the solution I found while checking the code behind the examples on the angular-chart site (http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/examples/app.js) was to set animation duration to 0 in the options. In Angular, using angular-charts this can be done in the controller using the chart-options directive as seen in the external linked code:

Controller

```
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.options = {animation: {duration: 0}};
}])
```

View

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line"
  chart-options="options"
></canvas>
```

Or globally using ChartJsProvider in the config method of the app:

```
app.config(function(ChartJsProvider) {
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
      animation: {duration: 0}
    });
})
```

I hope this helps, all of the info I posted can be found in the chart.js documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html